# git: check when the last fetch was run

Tags: git, bash

I have a script that shows the last few log changes, but if a fetch hasn't been ran in a day or two, I want the script to run it manually.

Here's sample bash code of how it would work:

```
#!/bin/bash

# this is what I need:
last_fetch_date=`git fetch --show-last-fetch-date`

# do the math to see how long ago
timestamp=`date -d "$last_fetch_date" +%s`
now=`date +%s`
diff=`echo $now - $timestamp | bc -l`

# two days
if [ `echo $diff' >= 2*24*60*60' | bc -l` == "1" ]; then
    git fetch --tags
fi
```

Comment: Just an idea to check modification date for `.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/master` or alike.... or maybe use hook

Comment: Checking the modification time of remote's ref files as suggested above might be a good surrogate for the last time fetch was run, but keep in mind that with packed refs, refs might not have files in that location.

Comment: How often are you running this script? It might make more sense to just call git fetch every time. If there's nothing to do, it doesn't take long. Or you could set up a cron job to do the fetch once a day.

Comment: It could be run by hand, or it could be called by another script that *just* did a fetch.

Comment: Also, on our server, `git fetch` usually asks for you password, even though we are caching passwords

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to know *when the last `git fetch` was run*, as git does not store that information. If you want to know, you will have to write a time stamp somewhere every time you run it.

However, you can find out *when `git fetch` last actually fetched something*. Every time `git fetch` fetches new commits, it updates the reflog. To see it, use e.g.

```
git reflog show --date=iso -n 1 origin/master
```

This will show the last change to `origin/master`, with the date. Caveat: This will also show when 
*you* modified it (by pushing).

Finally, it is probably easier to just fetch whenever it's convenient, without all this checking. `git fetch` runs very quickly if there's nothing to fetch.

Comment: So like this?

    `git reflog show --date=raw -n 1 origin/master | grep -oE '{[0-9]+' | sed 's%{%%'`

Comment: Why not just look at the timestamp on `FETCH_HEAD`?

Comment: @EdwardThomson: Yes, that seems to work. Why not make that an answer?

Comment: Extension of Edward Thomson with a more thorough answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29091536/how-can-i-see-the-time-of-my-last-git-pull, which answers the OP exactly

Comment: `git reflog show --date=iso origin/master -z |grep -E ': fetch|: pull'| grep -m1 -oP \@\{\(.*\)\}|sed -n "s/^.*@{\s*\(.*\)}/\1/p"`



Latest pull or fetch in reflog for origin/master remote branch.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I ended up doing, thanks to @sleske

```
#!/bin/bash

# do the math to see how long ago was the last fetch
 now=`date +%s`
 last_fetch=`git reflog show --date=raw -n 1 origin/master | grep -oE '{[0-9]+' | sed 's%{%%'`
 diff=`echo $now - $last_fetch | bc -l`
if [ `echo $diff' >= 2*24*60*60' | bc -l` == "1" ]; then
    git fetch -q
    git fetch --tags -q
fi
```