# How can I see the time of my last git pull?

Tags: git

I did a `git pull` but now want to know at what time that happened. Is there a way of checking the time of a pull? Note that NO changes came in when I did the pull. But perhaps the SSH connection is logged? I want to check this on my local machine rather than on the server. Using Linux, git version 2.3.3.

Comment: possibly this would help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993902/how-do-i-check-the-date-and-time-of-the-latest-git-pull-that-was-executed

Comment: You can check the modification date of the .git/FETCH_HEAD file, which will get update whenever you execute git pull command

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Git writes the FETCH_HEAD file every time you pull or fetch, even if there was nothing to pull. The file can be found at: `.git/FETCH_HEAD`. Just check the last modification time of that file.

In Linux you can use the following to check the last modified time:

```
date +%s -r .git/FETCH_HEAD
```

On OSX you can do the following to get the last modified time:

```
stat -f "%m" .git/FETCH_HEAD
```

Comment: Please where should I look for finding .git/FETCH_HEAD?

Comment: @franz1 the `.git` directory is at the root of a repository. `FETCH_HEAD` is a file in that directory. It only exists after at least one `git pull` or `git fetch` command has been given.